# When using 尽管 (jǐnguǎn) as "feel free to" in e.g. 你想看电影就尽管看吧, do we need the 你, 就, and/or 吧?

Tags: grammar, usage

When using 尽管 as "feel free to", do I always need to use it with 你?  Can I omit 就?  Can I omit 吧?

For example

> 你想看电影就尽管看吧。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples can be found in [Chinese Grammar Wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22feel_free%22_with_%22jinguan%22)：

> 大家 有 话 尽管 说 。
>   Feel free to talk if you have anything to say.
>   有 什么 问题 尽管 问 。
>   Feel free to ask if you have any questions.
>   有 什么 事 尽管 找 我 。
>   Feel free to ask me for help if you need anything.
>   这些 饮料 是 免费 的 ， 尽管 喝 。
>   Feel free to have these drinks. They are all free of charge.
>   想 吃 什么 尽管 点 ， 我 请客 。
>   Feel free to order anything you want. I'm buying.

And to answer your questions:

> do I always need to use it with 你

No. You can say: 让他有问题尽管问我. And from the example you can see that it can also used with some other pronouns, or with the subject omitted.

> can I omit 就

Not in your example sentence, but it can be used without 就. See the examples above.

> can I omit 吧

Yes. And "吧" can be omitted from your example sentence.

Answer (score 0):

No, the simplest form is 尽管+verb.

尽管看

It is a little aggressive. A boss might say 尽管做, 出事我负责.